# insert attributes from one xml source into another if a condition is met using xpath or xsl

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I will need to map the sourc1.xml elements `N1` and `VALUE` if the condition of `DEVICE_ID` is equal with source2.xml `id`. The desired output is shown in `output.xml`. I tried `xsl:copy` but to no avail and it doesn't work as specified.

---

source1.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<ResultSets>
  <ResultSet>
    <Row>
      <ID>1</ID>
      <LAST_UPDATED>2015-05-06 13:21:03.0</LAST_UPDATED>
      <N1>10</N1>
      <VALUE>abc</VALUE>
      <DEVICE_ID>200</DEVICE_ID>
    </Row>
    <Row>
      <ID>2</ID>
      <LAST_UPDATED>2015-05-06 13:21:03.0</LAST_UPDATED>
      <N1>11</N1>
      <VALUE>def</VALUE>
      <DEVICE_ID>300</DEVICE_ID>
    </Row>
  </ResultSet>
</ResultSets>
```

---

source2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<Head>
  <Back id="100000">
    <Back id="110000" name="level1">
      <Back id="200"/>
    </Back>
    <Back id="110001" name="level2">         
      <Back id="300"/>
    </Back>
  </Back>
</Head>
```

---

output.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<Head>
  <Back id="100000">
    <Back id="110000" name="level1">
      <Back id="200" newAttr1="abc" newAttri2="10"/>
    </Back>
    <Back id="110001" name="level2">         
      <Back id="300" newAttr1="def" newAttri2="11"/>
    </Back>
  </Back>
</Head>
```

Comment: `source2.xml` is missing an end-tag `</Back>`

Comment: Please indicate XSLT 1.0 or 2.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="no"/>
    <xsl:param name="reference" select="'source1.xml'"/>

    <xsl:template match="//Back[not(Back)]">
        <xsl:variable name="id" select="@id"/>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:attribute name="newAttr1"
                           select="document($reference)//Row[DEVICE_ID=$id]/VALUE"/>
            <xsl:attribute name="newAttri2" 
                           select="document($reference)//Row[DEVICE_ID=$id]/N1"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This stylesheet creates the desired output. It adds the new attributes to those `Back` elements that don't have `Back` as children.

The stylesheet takes the name of the reference-file as parameter `$reference`. That is used via the function `document()` to address those `Row`'s with the correct `DEVICE_ID`.

It should be noted that the template generates empty attributes in case the corresponding `DEVICE_ID` isn't found.

Comment: The lowest children back element